# Tenant mode is working in angularjs but not in angular 14

Tags: angular, angularjs, spring, multi-tenant

In the old angularjs code and spring backend (both js and spring are build in to same war) we have tenant mode and normal mode.
in normal mode the url looks like

```
http://localhost:4200/#!/dashboard
```

in tenant mode the url looks like.

```
http://localhost:4200/tenant/tenant1/#!/dashboard
```

to access the tenant mode we accessed as follows.

```
http://localhost:4200/tenant/tenant1
```

then in the back end we have filter to checks whether the url has /tenant/some-id and the backend return the index.html and then it is redirected to dashboard so the dashboard url looks like

```
http://localhost:4200/tenant/tenant1/#!/dashboard
```

Now i have migrated to angular 14 and backend is spring framework and now also both FE and BE are coupled into single war.

and when i try to access the same tenant in angular 14 using the url.

```
http://localhost:4200/tenant/tenant1
```

so i get the index.html from the backend but the url is getting changed to

```
http://localhost:4200/#/dashboard
```

instead of

```
http://localhost:4200/tenant/tenant1/#!/dashboard
```

I cant able to understand why /tenant/tenant1 is getting removed from the url. which was not the case of angularjs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by removing

```
<base href="/" />
```

from index.html of angular app.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the baseurl tag in the `index.html` from

```html
        <base href="/" />
```

to

```html
        <base href="./" />
```